# Ability to view WIFI connection details?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi

I've recently entered the mac world by getting my very first macbook pro and now am living with the differences of "thinking differently".  One thing I can't seem to find is any details on my connection.

Is there a way to see if the wifi I am connected to is B/G/N etc; Or does this require some custom app?

It is hard not having 'advanced options' ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold *Alt* when clicking at the *AirPort icon* on the menu bar. It should say `PHY Mode: 802.11.x`, where x is the type of connection.

[image]

You can also launch Wireless Diagnostics from that menu to capture packets and graph signal and noise measurements.

Comment: Hmm wonder what else this magical ALT button does

Comment: well in finder, if you click the "go" menu while holding control/alt it will allow you to go to Library